# sending php SMTP mail connection error

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send SMTP mail using PHPMailer 
And here is my code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxxx@xxxx.net";
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->From = "xxxx@xxxx.net";
$mail->FromName = "XXXXXXX";
$mail->addAddress("xxxx@xxxxx.com", "XXXXXXXXX");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

and It gives me that error

> Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

I saw there wiki in https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I've stopped my firewall,opensssl is working , my host,password,and username are correct .

In the debug he gave me that

> Password command failed

then he gave me

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: which OS are you using ?

Comment: Did you enable SMTP in your gmail account settings?

Comment: You've skipped all the other output that `SMTPDebug = 3` will produce. It's very, very likely you are running into the known issues with gmail auth described in the guide, and answered many times on SO.